# Help needed on installation of USB ethernet adapter in Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, ethernet

I am totally new to Ubuntu. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 now. The problem I am facing is that I use PPPOE connection for internet, and as I have some problem in the LAN port on my laptop,I use a USB ethernet adapter,but i am unable to install the ethernet adapter in Ubuntu, I have CD for the ethernet adapter where there is a folder named "Linux". But I am not able to find any way to install the driver,and as I can not install the driver,I am not able to connect to internet. Any help on this will be appreciated.

The command lsusb shows the following:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0fe6:9700 Kontron (Industrial Computer Source / ICS Advent) DM9601 Fast Ethernet Adapter
```

The command ifconfig -a;cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf;cat /etc/network/interfaces shows the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:d4:44:bb:e7:50  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:53:44:58  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe53:4458/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6078 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:31 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:877862 (877.8 KB)  TX bytes:4710 (4.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:13273 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13273 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1321986 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:1321986 (1.3 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:ec:99:a6:85:81  
          inet addr:192.168.43.212  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::26ec:99ff:fea6:8581/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:18759800 (18.7 MB)  TX bytes:3901642 (3.9 MB)

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth1 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
```

Comment: Is it a USB adapter?, can you give some more details and also run the command "lsusb" and paste the line referring to this adapter in the output... this will allow people to know what specific chip is in this device and hence what you need to do.

Comment: the command shows the following output:

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0fe6:9700 Kontron (Industrial Computer Source / ICS Advent) DM9601 Fast Ethernet Adapter

Answer (score 2):

Device 0fe6:9700 is supported on 14.04.3 without any 3rd party disk, so you probably don't need to worry, just plug it in and use it.

You can verify that the driver you have installed supports it thusly:-

modinfo dm9601 | grep -i 0fe6.9700

Comment: But I can not. In the upper left side of the screen, I can see this writing:

Ethernet Networks(Ofe6 USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adapter
Device not managed

Comment: And the command modinfo dm9601 | grep -i 0fe6.9700 gives following output:

alias:          usb:v0FE6p9700d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*

Comment: OK, so both those results point to the device having an appropriate driver, but I believe the system has seen your wired connection and elected not to manage the wireless... 
Can you paste the output of the following commands, so that I can see what is presently configured.

Comment: ifconfig -a;cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf;cat /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: Sir, I have updated my post with the result of the command

Comment: Ahh, sorry I had got slightly off track, the information you added is very useful... If I understand correctly you have a working wireless connection, and previously had a PPPOE connection over an on board ethernet connection, but the device has a fault, and you are trying to use the USB connection instead?... 
From the information included, I can see that you have 2 wired ethernet connections, and a wireless connection.... 
It's hard to tell from that output which is the USB one, but it may be that you need to review the configuration of the pppoe connection as it explicitly specifies a port.

Comment: You can check which port (eth0 or eth1) has the cable plugged in with eg "ethtool eth0" or "ethtool eth1", look for "Link Detected",... my guess is that the issue is that now your pppoe setup is pointing to the wrong device, because your usb ethernet port appears to be up fine.

Comment: Sir,ethtool eth1 provides link detected

Comment: Sir, for your kind information, I have never used PPPOE connection in Ubuntu, I used the connection in windows

Comment: Then I am slightly confused about what your problem is... are you trying to make PPPOE work, or are you wanting your USB ethernet to connect as normal and be "managed" by network manager...

Comment: If your goal is to have your USB ethernet work as "normal", then the reason it does not is because it is has been set to "manually configured" by some previous configuration you made with PPPOE....

Comment: To return it to normal, if you cannot do so with whatever PPPOE config tool you used (which I am not familiar with)... then you would need to remove the last 2 blocks, leaving only "auto lo
iface lo inet loopback" from /etc/network/interfaces.